# How to delete duplicate section with same startpoint and endpoint by Python or Shell

Tags: python, shell

I am new with python and i have a txt including some defination
such like this:

```
.subckt inv a z
mp z a vdd vdd pch
mn z a gnd gnd nch
.ends

.subckt pg in out clk clkb
mp in clkb out vdd pch
mn in clk  out gnd nch
.ends

.subckt inv a z
mp z a vdd vdd pch
mn z a gnd gnd nch
.ends
```

Every section begin with `.subckt` and end with `.ends`
And the first section and the third section are the same, how can i delete the duplicated defination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it! Really excited, add `b` when the txt including any other content,`list2` for using the original order

```
file=r'C:\Users\file.txt'

with open(file) as txt:
    a=re.findall(r'\.subckt.*\.ends',txt.read(),re.M|re.S)
    txt.seek(0)
    b=re.sub(''.join(a),'',txt.read(),flags=re.S|re.M)
    print(b.strip()+'\n')
    list1=''.join(a).split('\n\n')
    list2=list(set(list1))
    list2.sort(key=list1.index)
    for line in list2:
        print(line+'\n')
```